# Odd behaviour of g++ and clang++ with enabled optimization

Tags: c++, c++11, g++, clang++

Here's my program:

print.hpp:

```
#pragma once

#include <iostream>

template<size_t p>
void print()
{
  std::cout << "" << __FILE__ << "" <<  __LINE__ << "" << std::endl;
  exit(0);
}
```

print.cpp:

```
#include "print.hpp"

template<>
void print<13>()
{
  std::cout << "Unlucky." << std::endl;
}
```

main.cpp:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "print.hpp"

int main()
{
  std::cout << "Started." << std::endl;
  print<13>();
  std::cout << "Exiting." << std::endl;
}
```

When I compile that with `g++ main.cpp print.cpp -O0 -std=c++11 && ./a.out` it works fine (output is:

```
Started.
Unlucky.
Exiting.
```

).
However, if'd I compile that with `g++ main.cpp print.cpp -O1 -std=c++11 && ./a.out` it would give me a segmentation fault with the output:

```
Started.
Unlucky.
Speicherzugriffsfehler //German for memory access error
```

Almost the same with clang++, without optimization it would do its job just fine 
and with -O1 or higher it outputs that:

```
Started.
Unlucky.
./print.hpp8
```

Why is that?

Comment: I do not see any code that prints "Hi" are you sure the code shown is used?

Comment: You could compile with `g++ -g -O1 -std=c++11 main.cpp print.cpp` and use the `gdb`  debugger (you can use both `-g` and `-O1` )

Comment: @Slava corrected. thank you.

Comment: Your program is ill-formed, see details in the dupe

Answer (score 1):

You need to declare the template specialization in the .hpp file.

```
template<size_t p>
void print()
{
  std::cout << "" << __FILE__ << "" <<  __LINE__ << "" << std::endl;
  exit(0);
}

// Declare the specialization.
template<> void print<13>();
```

Without the declaration in the .hpp file, I get a linker error with g++ 6.4.0.

```
.../Local/Temp/cctCC5MK.o:print.cc:(.text+0x0): multiple definition of `void print<13ul>()'
.../Local/Temp/ccgodRUG.o:socc.cc:(.text$_Z5printILm13EEvv[_Z5printILm13EEvv]+0x0): first defined here
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

I am not sure how you are able to successfully build your program without the declaration.

Comment: Your answer does not answer the "*why*" bit.

Comment: well, I used the same version of g++ on x86_64 Linux and it was the exact same code as I posted.

Comment: @DariusDuesentrieb, I don't know how to explain that.